# I don't know what's missing in my code. It says "Expected identifier or '('"

Tags: objective-c

I don't know what's missing in my code. It says "Expected identifier or '('" Please help. These are the lines that have this error.

```
#import "ViewController.m"

{
- (BOOL)textFieldShouldReturn:(UITextField *)textField;
    NSLog(self.myTextField.text)
    [self.myTextField resignFirstResponder];
    return YES;
}

@end
```

Comment: You need a `{` after `(UITextField *)textField` instead of an `;`. You're also missing a `;` after the `NSLog()` line.

Comment: Given the vast number of issues with this code, may I politely suggest finding yourself some good tutorials on the basics of the Objective-C programming language. Time spent now learning the basics of the language will get you along a lot faster.

Answer (score 3):

First, you normally `#import` header (.h) files, not source (.m) files. So, your first line should probably be:

```
#import "ViewController.h"
```

Normally, such an import would be near the top of a source file. The method definition that follows has to be inside of an `@implementation`, which would normally appear between any imports and any method definitions. So, you should add a line like:

```
@implementation ViewController
```

The `@end` at the bottom of your code snippet corresponds to this `@implementation`.

Then, you seem to have swapped the method signature line and the line with the opening brace for that method. You have:

```
    {
    - (BOOL)textFieldShouldReturn:(UITextField *)textField;
```

When you should have:

```
    - (BOOL)textFieldShouldReturn:(UITextField *)textField;
    {
```

You don't need the semicolon (`;`) on the end of that line, but it's actually harmless.

Finally, the statement where you call `NSLog()` is incomplete because it needs to be terminated with a semicolon:

```
    NSLog(self.myTextField.text);
```

Perhaps you accidentally typed the semicolon that you meant for that line on the line above, which would explain the extraneous semicolon there.

Comment: And the `NSLog` should be `NSLog(@"%@", self.myTextField.text);`. Otherwise the code will crash if the user happens to type a `%` character into the text field.